# What is the shortest time?

Tags: derivatives, classical-mechanics, kinematics

Piroska is Red Riding Hood, Nagymama is grandma on the picture:

[image]

The wolf attacked grandma, who lives on the coastline. As soon as Red Riding Hood heard Granny's scream, she went to help her. On what route should RRH move to save Granny within the shortest time? In the woods RRH runs with $v_1$ speed, and she swims with $v_2$ speed in the lake.

(The brown part is the woods and the blue is the lake. RRH can swim in a straight line since the lake won't drift her.)

Comment: Ohh sorry, I thought all kinds of sciene is welcome here, hence the mechanics quiestion.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your question! I hope I could improve it correctly. Although there is an easy math solution for the problem, probably it is more ontopic for physicists. But maybe you will get also a math answer.

Comment: Well an equation with parameters should be made and since we need the shortest time, it needs to be derivated.

Comment: I think there are 3 cases. First is when RRH runs straight to the coastline then swims to ma. 2ns is where she runs to the coastline in a way that she needs to swim the shortest route that is the distance btw the two coastlines, and the third option is where the two speeds ara equal thus we just put a straight line btw RRH and grandma.

Comment: No, it is more complex. The solution is some lagrange thing. You can also derive it, but it will be long. But there is also an easy solution for the problem, essentially using refraction.

Comment: I was told that somehow Snell's law should be applied.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.math.wpi.edu/Course_Materials/MA1024A97/projects/project2.html